# UITableView bug when adding a UIButton programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

i have a table view. And im adding two buttons to each cell:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        newBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,10,25,55)];
         [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [newBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [newBtn setEnabled:YES];
         newBtn.hidden = YES;
         [cell addSubview:newBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(280,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         subBtn.hidden = YES;
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];

    } 
return cell;
}
```

And i want to have the buttons hidden at first, then when the table is in "edit" mode, i want these buttons to appear. and when the table leaves "edit" mode, the buttons disappear.

I can get one of the cells buttons to do this.

```
    - (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.editing) 
    {
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        EditButton.title = @"Edit";
        subBtn.hidden = YES;
        newBtn.hidden = YES;
    } 
    else 
    {
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        EditButton.title = @"Done";
        subBtn.hidden = NO;
        newBtn.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

But the problem is: when i do this, only the very LAST cell gets the buttons. They appear and disappear exactly when i want, but only the last cell! No other cells get any buttons, could someone please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing this `subBtn` and `newBtn` point to the buttons of the last cell. A better approach would be to subclass `UITableViewCell` and make the buttons instance variables. Then overwrite `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` and hide/show the buttons there.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little better? Im a noob! lol What do you mean by "subcall"? also if its not too much of a hassle, could you please please provide some sample code that way i can study it and use it in my program? Thanks for the help!

Comment: also, how do my buttons "point" to the buttons of the last cell? im not sure what code does it! thanks again! :D

Comment: I meant 'subclass'. Look everytime you do "subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];" your pointer is obviously overridden, so at the end it points at the buttons of the last cell. Don't know how to better explain this.

Comment: Okay, i get what you are saying. However, im unsure of how to fix it. Shall i allocate and initialize the buttons in the `init` method? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

How are you firing the 'edit button' method? If you are using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, then only the row selected will show the buttons. You could iterate through indexpath.row for visible cells, unhiding each line.

Comment: i am just calling this method from a button on a nav bar and thanks for the help!